# Issue passing a dictionary into Fargate Docker container

Tags: docker, boto3, aws-fargate

I have a container that runs fine locally consisting of a simple python script that accepts a dictionary converted to a string as a system argument and prints out the key/value pairs:

calc.py:

```
import sys
import json
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Entered in main")
    print(f"Function name: {sys.argv[0]}")
    #load
    print(sys.argv[1])
    payload = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    for k,v in payload.items():
        print(f"Key: {k},Value: {v}")
```

I build this as a docker container using an entrypoint with an environmental varible:

```
   ENTRYPOINT python3 calc.py "${LAMBDA_PAYLOAD}"
```

This allows me to run a test docker script of

```
docker run -e LAMBDA_PAYLOAD="{\"names\":\"J.J. Robichard\",\"Age\":25}" calc
```

which successfully prints out the key/value pairs.

When I put this into an AWS ECS Fargate task using boto3 and overriding the environmental variable by using:

```
'environment': [
      {
       'name': 'LAMBDA_PAYLOAD',
        'value': "{\"names\":[\"J.J. Robichard\",\"April\"],\"years\":[25,29]}"
       },
   ],
```

I get the print(sys.argv[1]) returns:

```
{"names":["J.J.
```

and everything breaks down. How do I get the task to accept a string with space?  I've tried "\ " and f"""{}""", but nothing is working.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference from what you've shown, but your `docker run -e` invocation doesn't have a space in the name field; do you get the same result locally if you include it?  Can you directly use `os.environ['LAMBDA_PAYLOAD']` without trying to route it through a command-line argument?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I was able to pass the dictionary through by encoding it as follows:

```
#inital dictionary
payload = {"names":"J.J. Robichard","April","years":[25,29]}
#converted to string
payload_s = json.dumps(payload).replace("\"","\\\"")
#this was input into the boto3 client as the value
```

on the other side, I had to do this:

```
input_1 = sys.argv[1]
payload = json.loads(input_1.replace("\\\"", "\""))
```